# Disable `math text inlined` color in all display math environments (beamer)

Tags: beamer, arrays, inline

I color my inline math in `beamer` to improve readability. However, when I use `array` environment, it will include some inline math being put inside `array` which is display math. I would like inline math to be colored only when it is put outside any display math environment. Also, the tags of the equations seem to change to the same color of the inline math. I would rather like it black

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamercolor{math text inlined}{fg=SpringGreen3}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        \bar{I}_{R}(n) = \left\lbrace
            \begin{array}{ccl}
                I_{R, \thinspace i} &\text{if} &n = i
            \\
                I_{R, \thinspace j} &\text{if} &n = j
            \\
                0 & \text{if} &n \neq i \text{~or~} j
            \end{array}
                        \right.
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility could be to change the colour back to black by using custom defined column types:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamercolor{math text inlined}{fg=SpringGreen3}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\color{black}}c}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\color{black}}l}

\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\color{black}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation}
        \bar{I}_{R}(n) = \left\lbrace
            \begin{array}{CCL}
                I_{R, \thinspace i} &\text{if} &n = i
            \\
                I_{R, \thinspace j} &\text{if} &n = j
            \\
                0 & \text{if} &n \neq i \text{~or~} j
            \end{array}
                        \right.
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]